# How to use complex SQL in yii2

Tags: sql, sql-server, yii2

I am new to yii2 and I'm having problem with my SQL. How can I write my sql

```
WITH TabDelimOfValue as (SELECT personaltab.last_name, personaltab.first_name, personaltab.middle_name, personaltab.cur_assign, personaltab.appttype, personaltab.dateorig_appt,svctable.positionID, svctable.datefr, svctable.dateto, svctable.empno, svctable.grade_incre as val
FROM svctable INNER JOIN personaltab ON personaltab.empno = svctable.empno WHERE svctable.dateto = '1900-01-01' AND personaltab.perstatus like 'ACTIVE')
SELECT
        empno,
        CAST(substring(val, 0, charindex('-', val)) as int) as grade,
        substring(val, (charindex('-', val) + 1), (len(val) - charindex('-', reverse(val)))) as increment,
        val as grade_incre, last_name, first_name, middle_name, cur_assign, appttype, dateorig_appt, positionID, datefr, dateto
FROM TabDelimOfValue ORDER BY grade DESC, increment DESC, positionID;
```

to SQLDataProvider?

Comment: Maybe is better to write an stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for complex query you can use  a create command  eg:

```
$sql = " WITH TabDelimOfValue as (
          SELECT personaltab.last_name
              , personaltab.first_name
              , personaltab.middle_name
              , personaltab.cur_assign
              , personaltab.appttype
              , personaltab.dateorig_appt
              , svctable.positionID
              , svctable.datefr
              , svctable.dateto
              , svctable.empno
              , svctable.grade_incre as val
          FROM svctable 
          INNER JOIN personaltab ON personaltab.empno = svctable.empno 
          WHERE svctable.dateto = '1900-01-01'  AND personaltab.perstatus like 'ACTIVE'
      )
      SELECT
                empno
              , CAST(substring(val, 0, charindex('-', val)) as int) as grade
              , substring(val, (charindex('-', val) + 1), (len(val) - charindex('-', reverse(val)))) as increment
              , val as grade_incre
              , last_name
              , first_name
              , middle_name
              , cur_assign
              , appttype
              , dateorig_appt
              , positionID
              , datefr
              , dateto
      FROM TabDelimOfValue 
      ORDER BY grade DESC, increment DESC, positionID;";

$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);

$models = $command->queryAll();
```